# Search Query Tokenizer

Tags: algorithm, tokenize, lexical-analysis

We're trying to add a simple search functionality to our website that lists restaurants. We try to detect the place name, location, and place features from the search string, something like "cheap restaurants near cairo" or "chinese and high-end food in virginia".

What we are doing right now it tokenizing the query and searching in the tables with the least performance cost first (the table of prices (cheap-budget-expensive-high-end) is smaller than the tables of the places list). Is this the right approach ?

--
Regards.
Yehia

Comment: On long term plans, and scalability issues, I'm not sure how far will this approach go. Have you considered using an Industry standard Search Engine like Solr (http://lucene.apache.org/solr/)?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you should build sets of synonyms (e.g. cheap, low budget, etc go into synset:1) and map each token from the search string to one of those groups.

Btw, it will be easy to handle spelling mistakes here since this is genereally a pretty small search space. Edit distance, common k-grams, ... anything should be alright.

In a next step you should build inverted index lists for each of those syn-groups the map to a sorted list of restaurants that can be associated with that property. For each syngroup from a query, get all those lists and simply intersect them.

Words that cannot be mapped to one of those synsets will probably have to be ignored unless you have some sort of fulltexts about the restaurants that you could index as well. In that can you can also buildsuch restaurant lists for "normal" words and intersect them as well. But this would already be quite close to classical search engines and it might be a good idea to use a technology like apache lucence. Without fulltexts I don't think you'd need such a thing because an inverted index of snygroups is really easy to process on your own.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you may be missing how misspelled queries are handled.